# Using Selenium Ide how to focus on the textbox before or after providing an input?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The field is only activated when I physically click on it or with a Tab. My selenium script can input the value but the system treats it as no entry (ignores entered value). I tried all of the below but the event didn't fire:

1. sendKeys|xpath|${KEY_TAB}
2. fireEvent |xpath|focus
3. focus|xpath|
4. ClickAt|xpath
5. sendKeys|xpath|value${KEY_ENTER}

Answer (score 0):

fireEvent | xpath | blur worked for me